# The parameter 'exePath' is invalid

Tags: asp.net, exception, configuration, iis-6

I am trying to setup a website on IIS. It is basically a copy of an existing website (working) that we have that is hosted on another server. The two server's OS is running the same OS Windows Server 2003 and both site is running on IIS 6. The source code is the same since it was just copied from Site A. Only difference is that the database is now connected to a new database.

When I open a page on the site, it throws me this error.

> The parameter 'exePath' is invalid
>
> Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
> ASP.NET Files\fias\576e43ba\53e00dbc\App_Web_bndnkzt8.0.cs    Line: 0

I am not sure what is causing this. But I am sure that it is not on the code since it's just copied from the other working site.

I am looking into permissions on directory. I already changed permissions to say FULL Control but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Would you post the part of your code that references `exePath`.  And where are you storing the file?

Comment: make sure you have configured the right version of ASP.Net in IIS, under the Application Pool.

Comment: i'm not sure which part references exePath. the file is stored in a shared directory. i made sure that the account running IIS has Full Control over the directory.

Comment: IIS was configured as a copy of the existing one as well. I saved the existing one to a configuration file and attached that to the new server. i then made the changes that are needed so i am also sure that AppPool is the same. :(